# option from one dropdown

Tags: jquery

initial Reason and Status -> SELECT.
ious values are not getting reset).

Answer (score 0):

May be you are asking for this. Please let me know if you want something else.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


      $("#reason").change(function() {

        var el = $(this) ;
        el.html("");

        if(el.val() === "Terms & Conditions" ) {

        $("#status").append("   <option value ='CONTINUERIDERBENEFIT'>Continue Rider Benefit</option>");
        }
          else if(el.val() === "Death Before Login" || el.val() === "Issuance" || el.val() === "Fictious Life" ) {
           $("#status").append(" <option value='VoidBasePolicyRider'>Void Base Policy and Rider</option>");
            }
```

Comment: el.html("") -> notneeded.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is not working.

```
  else if(el.val() === "Death Before Login" || "Issuance" || "Fictious Life" )
```

Try this.

Comment: I  replaced if with else if for second one,  it works but I need option(Select) as value to be the first value for both Terms & Conditions and for Death Before Login....

Answer (score 0):

ok now i have understand what you wanted. You are just thinking in a different perspective and making it complex.. I have written a very simple code to solve your issue.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
       $("#status option[id='a']").hide();
       $("#status option[id='b']").hide();

       $("#reason").change(function() {
           var el = $(this);
           if(el.val() === "Terms & Conditions" ) {
               $("#status option[id='a']").show();
               $("#status option[id='b']").hide();
           } else if(el.val() === "Death Before Login" || el.val() === "Issuance" || el.val() === "Fictious Life" ) {
               $("#status option[id='b']").show();
               $("#status option[id='a']").hide();
          } else {
               $("#status option[id='a']").hide();
               $("#status option[id='b']").hide();
          }
       });  
     });
```

Status:

```
<select id="status" name="status">
   <option>Select</option>
   <option id='a' value='CONTINUERIDERBENEFIT'>Continue Rider Benefit</option>
   <option id='b' value='VoidBasePolicyRider'>Void Base Policy and Rider</option>
 </select>
```